# Is it bad practice to pass $scope to a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it bad practice to pass $scope to a service? Could it even cause memory leaks since controllers can be instantiated multiple times?

Example:

```
.controller('TestController', function ($scope, TestService) {

    $scope.loadData = function() {
        // loadData will set some properties on the scope
        TestService.loadData($scope);
    };

});
```

Comment: IMO, yes it is not the best way to do things.  It is usually best to separate service logic from UI binding.  This allows the services to be used in many places and provide functionality.  It is just good separation of concerns.

Comment: It's just not how services should be used. They should be independant to your controller scope. Setting properties to the scope is the controller's job.

Comment: It seems like what you want to do is something similar to `$scope.loadData = function () { $scope.myData = TestService.loadData(); }` Why do you need to pass the $scope to your service? If you need to pass arguments to the loadData, pass them explicitly, so you set a clear interface how to use the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the memory leak part since $scope is being placed on the stack, but yeah, you want to separate your concerns and return data from your services, not bind data to your controller within them.

Also, can lead to confusion if someone else is looking at the controller code and can't figure out how some field within $scope got set.